# how to enable row count to automatically reorder in html

Tags: javascript, html

so let say i added row 1 2 3 4 5
if i delete row 2 3 , 
how do i make the current row become from 1 4 5 into 1 2 3 
and add new row start from 4 instead of 6. the following is the example of my current code

this is the fiddle, somehow my add row didnt work in fiddle but it is working at my site
http://jsfiddle.net/q0kcnk6r/

```
</script> 
   //$('btnAddd').click(function(){
        var count =0;

        function add(){


        $("#tblData tbody").append(
            "<tr>"+
            "<td ><input type='text' size ='2' value ='"+ ++count +"' /></td>"+
            "<td><input type='text' size ='43'/></td>"+
            "<td><input type='text' size ='4'/></td>"+
            "<td><img src='img/disk.jpg' class='btnSave'><img src='img/delete.png' class='btnDelete'/></td>"+
            "</tr>");

            $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);      
            $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    }; 


    function Save(){
        var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
        var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
        var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
        var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
        var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

        tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdPhone.html(tdPhone.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdEmail.html(tdEmail.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdButtons.html("<img src='img/delete.png' class='btnDelete'/><img src='img/edit.png' class='btnEdit'/>");

        $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    }; 


    function Edit(){
        var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
        var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
        var tdPhone = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
        var tdEmail = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
        var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

        tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='"+tdName.html()+"'/>");
        tdPhone.html("<input type='text' id='txtPhone' value='"+tdPhone.html()+"'/>");
        tdEmail.html("<input type='text' id='txtEmail' value='"+tdEmail.html()+"'/>");
        tdButtons.html("<img src='img/disk.jpg' class='btnSave'/>");

        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
        $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    };


    function Delete(){
        var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
        par.remove();
    }; 


    $(function(){
        //Add, Save, Edit and Delete functions code
        $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
        $("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
    });






        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1" id="tblData">         
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width ="20px">ID</th>
                    <th width ="360px">Item</th>
                    <th width ="20px">Quantity</th>
                    <th><input type="button" id="btnAddd" value="New" onclick="add()" /></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You could call an initialize function after delete, that will loop through all your rows, and give them new IDs...

Comment: Can you share as a JSFiddle so that we can play around with it?

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery, you can set the value of an element based on the index of a selector. In your case, you may do it like this:

First step, add `name` attributes to the `input` in the ID column, or other thing to select them:

```
<input name="row-id" />
```

Then, select only these inputs, and set the value based on its position in the document:

```
function reorder() {
    $('input[name="row-id"]').val(function(index) {
        return index+''; 
    });
}
```

Your code has some flaws, like:

1. Avoid binding click handlers to the same elements multiple times. Try to bind them once, only bind to the **new** elements when you are creating them.
2. Try to avoid typing a lot of HTML markup strings in your JavaScript and adding it to the document. Try to understand how the DOM works and how to work with it.
3. Don't use images as they were buttons. The semantics differ and you will encounter a lot of trouble to make they look like and act like buttons.

I've added just the `reorder` function to your JSFiddle just to show it working for you, but did not fix the flaws I've mentioned: http://jsfiddle.net/q0kcnk6r/6/